# SSL CONNECTIVITY: using self signed certificates

Tags: openssl

Is it possible for ssl connection handshake to happen using self signed certificate with certificate authority

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get most client applications to accept a self signed cert from a server, however, in many cases it requires that you use a command line option or a setting in a config file.

If the cert is signed by a CA ... then it is not a self signed cert, it is a CA signed cert.  The only real question from there is the CA trusted by the client application.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it nicely. But i have another question if it is possible to authenticate a certificate with CA being blank/empty? I mean how can client trust a self signed certificate which has CA blank/empty.

Comment: @fiddle: For a CA-signed cert on the Internet, the child cert's issuer and the CA cert's subject must be nonempty; see rfc5280 4.1.2.4. Self-signed certs other than CA roots (which must have issuer = subject and subject nonempty) aren't standard at all, and in theory a self-signed end-entity cert could have subject empty and SAN present and thus issuer empty, but in practice I wouldn't count on that working and I certainly wouldn't advise it. On a private network you can probably do whatever people on that private network agree to.